# Eel Application using chrome extensions

Tags: python-3.x, eel

I saw Eel module which is used to make gui applications with Python and web languages. I tried that out and found that my application is using chrome extensions.

Like I have `darkreader`  installed, and whenever I am enabling it, my application is getting affected.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Eel allows you to pass flags to the underlying Chrome browser instance using the `cmd_args` argument to the `eel.start()` function. You can read more about this in the "App options" section in the [Eel documentation](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel#app-options).

Maybe try something like:

```py
eel.start('main.html', cmdline_args=['--disable-extensions'])
```

I don't think there is an official list of Chrome flags available, but I tend to use [this page](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) as a starting point. Maybe there is a more appropriate flag than the one I quickly found.

Comment: That does not do the trick :(

Comment: That's unfortunate! You're at the mercy of the underlying browser applications and their behaviors. For our learning purposes, did you try any flags other than --disable-extensions? Also, did you completely shut down the Chrome process before starting your Eel app with these flags (some flags only take effect when the Chrome process starts up). Lastly, another less-than-ideal option would be to manually select a browser other than Chrome when starting your Eel application ("mode" param)... it's not a "solution", but something to consider if no other alternatives are presented. Best of luck!